# Cannot Connect to Windows Server Using a Particular IP

Tags: security, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, network-adapter, iis

We have a Windows server 2008 running as web server. The Server has two IP's (A and B) added to it. We were able to use both the IP's for remote desktop connections and FTP connections.

All of a sudden the server is not accessible from any of our office computers when we try to connect using IP A. But we can connect using the IP B.

But both the IPs A and B are working fine when we tried to login from a computer outside our network.

Can some one please help?

Answer (score 0):

Is IP A by chance the same as the WAN IP for your network?  If so, what might be happening is your router/firewall is treating that request as a redirect.  See this post of what might be a similar issue:  http://forums.devshed.com/networking-help-109/accessing-server-using-wan-ip-from-inside-lan-195793.html  Basically, if this is the case, what you'll want to do is use the LAN IP to connect to your server rather than the WAN IP.

If that's not what's going on here, my apologies for the assumption.  A good method for beginning to diagnose just what exactly is happening to your request when you attempt to connect via IP A is to use `tracert` to determine the path that your request is following.  Here's some helpful info from Microsoft on how to use that command:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162326

Since we can assume that this is not a port or firewall issue on your server, as you're able to connect via the WAN, then I'd suspect that it has something to do with the way the traffic is being routed locally.  If you have access to them, I'd check the logs for your router to see what is happening to that request.  Please feel free to post the results you got from using the tracert command as well as router logs here if you'd like me to take a look.